# Create a single album/post on Imgur and add multiple images to it, without creating a post per image?

Tags: python, api, imgur

When using the Imgur website directly, I can easily

1. create a new post, and
2. add images to it, without
3. creating a new post per image.

This seems to be the way the posts are supposed to work, kinda like albums.

However, I cannot seem to find the entry point in the Imgur API with which to do the same.
I try to upload a couple of images, and then create an album, then add the images to it.
But this results in a post per image, instead of a single post containing these images.

I am using the python imgurpython API (yes I know it is not maintained, but it seems to still correspond quite well to the published API).

In short:

```
# imagepathlist contains a number of image paths that I want to upload into a single album
# client is an already-authenticated imgurpython.ImgurClient instance.

imagedata = []
for imagepath in imagepathlist:
    result = client.upload_from_path(imagepath, anon=False)
    imagedata.append(result)

imageids = [data['id'] for data in imagedata]
imagedeletehashes = [data['deletehash'] for data in imagedata]

albumspec = {
    'title': 'My album',
    'privacy': 'hidden',
    'ids': imageids,
    'deletehashes': imagedeletehashes,
}

albumdata = client.create_album(albumspec)
```

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around a bit, I realised that the first image was included in the album/post, but not the others - each one of these got their own post. So I tried a different approach; rather than add the image(s) to the album at time of the album's creation, I added it after the fact, as in

```
...
albumspec = {
    'title': 'My album',
    'privacy': 'hidden',
}

albumdata = client.create_album(albumspec)

client.album_add_images(albumid, imageids)
```

Now I get a single post, with all images residing in it.